# Search for an element in the VBA ArrayList

Tags: excel, vba, list, arraylist

I hope you are great! I want to search through a VBA ArrayList and get the index number, the problem is, with For loop, you can only get the exact matches' index. I have the most of my search element (highlighted in the red box) and I want to get the elements which highlighted in the blue box, is there any way to do this in VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the in-built function `InStr` to find an occurrence of one string inside another.

In your case change this:

```
If list(j) = search_element Then
```

To:

```
If InStr(1, list(j), search_element) > 0 Then
```

`InStr` returns the *position* of `search_element` within `list(j)`.  If the position is *above 0* then the string was found.  If it is `0` then nothing was found.

Therefore, this will be `true` if `search_element` occurs anywhere within `list(j)`.

The documentation for `InStr` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function).